# How to mount Linux_RAID on OS X

Tags: disk-utility

I have a NAS that broke and it used linu_RAID as its format type. How do I mount this in OS X?

Similar to this one...
https://superuser.com/questions/307639/how-can-i-mount-a-single-raid-1-disk-partition-as-ext3

Answer (score 1):

I found out it wasn't ext using the following command...

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk2s4 of=../disk1s3.header bs=1024 count=2
```

This told be it was XFS so I used fuse-xfs and it works as long as I access it with root privileges.